# PowerApps update data source with checkbox

Tags: checkbox, powerapps, powerapps-formula

I am new to PowerApps and need to bind a checkbox to a column in the data source (excel spreadsheet) so that when checked, I can change the `0` into a `1` in the data source.

```
OnSelect:Patch(Table1, ThisItem, { Active: If('chkActive'.Text = "1", true, false) })
```

I also want to bind a numeric column to the data source (excel spreadsheet) so that I can edit the data source.

```
OnChange:Patch(Table1, ThisItem, {'Editable amount (£)': 'TextInput6.Number'})
```

I am unable to link to the data source and am open to suggestions.